Regression model on edge list
I would like to fit a regression in which my data is links (edges) from the network and the output is weight of each link.
Income level is a node attribute and for each link two nodes are involved, so I have an edge list like this:



node_node
link
wight




a_b
high-high
3


a_d
high-low
4


a_f
high-medium
1


c_f
high-medium
5


d_f
low-medium
1



I'm interested in the relationship between link values and weight to see which combination of income level lead to change in weight.
How should I incorporate the link column into my regression model?
Should I input the link column into my regression model as dummy variables, or is there a better method?
